# converting number to pattern as DNA sequence : trying to solve this bioinformatics problem with python

Tags: python, bioinformatics

## which is to transform the integers 0, 1, 2, and 3 into the respective symbols A, C, G, and T.

```
def NumberToSymbol(index):
    SeqDict = {0:'A', 1:'C', 2:'G', 3:'T'}
    str_index = str(index)
    result = ""
    for i in str_index:
        result = result + SeqDict[int(i)]
    return result
```

## the quotient when dividing integer n by integer m as Quotient(n, m)

## For example, Quotient(11, 4) = 2

```
def Quotient(index,4):
    index = int(index/4)
    return index
```

## the remainder when dividing integer n by integer m as Remainder(n, m)

## For example, Remainder(11, 4) = 3.

```
def Remainder(index, 4)
    index = index%4
    return index
```

When computing Pattern = NumberToPattern(9904, 7), we divide 9904 by 4 to obtain a quotient of 2476 and a remainder of 0. This remainder represents the final nucleotide of Pattern, or NumberToSymbol(0) = A. We then iterate this process, dividing each subsequent quotient by 4, until we obtain a quotient of 0. The symbols in the nucleotide column, read upward from the bottom, yield Pattern = GCGGTAA.

```
def NumberToPatten(index, k):
    if K==1:
        return NumberToSymbol(index)
    else:
        prefixIndex = Quotient(index, 4)
        r = Remainder(index, 4)
        symbol = NumberToSymbol(r)
        PrefixPattern = NumberToPatten(prefixIndex, k -1)
        return str(PrefixPattern) + symbol
```

l have these 4 functions working together:
Input: Integers index and k.
Output: The string NumberToPattern(index, k).
for example:
input :  45 , 4
output: AGTC

Comment: Please don't change original question, just like that, Your initial question was to resolve some other error that you were getting during running the program

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let me help you understanding the problem first, Then tell you some ways to fix this problem

In python (or in any other programming language) function can have

**def fun_name(arg1, arg2):**  #Normal arguments

or

**def fun_name(arg, arg2=4)**: #Default value arguments, If user does not provide value for arg2 then default value i.e. 4 will be assigned.

```
def Quotient(index,4):
```

In your code you have defined a function named Quotient with argument index and other argument you have defined as "4", **which is literal, Variable name cannot be literal**.

> 

**Solution / Fix**

Solution 1. #Preferred #Default value argument, So if user passes the value it will take that else it will be assigned default value 4

```
def Quotient(index,divisor = 4):
    index = int(index/divisor)
    return index
```

Solution 2:# Instead of Literal use variable

```
def Quotient(index,divisor): 
    index = int(index/divisor)
    return index
```

Solution 3. # Pass just 1 variable from caller place

```
def Quotient(index): 
    index = int(index/4)
    return index
```

## Edited for other problem discussed on comment

**To transform 0112 to ACCG using NumberToSymbol function **

```
def NumberToSymbol(index): #Consider value of index is "0112" string and return will be ACCG
    SeqDict = {0:'A', 1:'C', 2:'G', 3:'T'}
    str_index = str(index)
    result = ""
    for i in str_index:
        result = result + SeqDict[int(i)]
    return result
```

Note: If you are facing problem calling this function, try passing value as string, byDefault python consider 0112 as Octal number so try sending it as "0112"

Comment: @AngleAli, To Avoid such error, Please type cast both variable to same type. For arithmetic operation both operand must be of same dataType

Comment: thank you and there is this function which need to be fixed: which is to transform the integers 0, 1, 2, and 3 into the respective symbols A, C, G, and T.
`def NumberToSymbol(index):
    SeqDict = {0:'A', 1:'C', 2:'G', 3:'T'}
    Symbol = Pattern[-1]
    return SeqDict[Symbol]`

Comment: what is the error in this function and can you tell me what is the use of argument index?

Comment: there is error in this line     `Symbol = index[-1]
TypeError: 'int' object is not subscriptable` l want to take this index "0, 1,2,3" qnd change is into symbol "A,C,G,T"

Comment: where is variable Pattern defined? and can you tell what is exact error?

Comment: there is no pattern variable, my mistake

Comment: l still can't fix this error above, `Symbol = index[-1] TypeError: 'int' object is not subscriptable`

Comment: you need to understand sub-script is of arrays or strings, not for integer, in case of string [-1] represent last character of variable

Comment: What is your expectation out of that function?

Comment: for example if l write 0112, l want it to return ACCG

Comment: how to fix this :  `result = result + SeqDict[int(i)]
ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: '.'`

Comment: what is the value you are passing to function? pass number only which has 0,1,2 or 4, else it will throw error, As code do not handle error scenarios

Comment: numbers as index

Comment: what do you mean by numbers as index,   Post the value you are tring to pass and getting the error

Comment: see my edited question to understand what l am trying to do with this whole code